# Can I "register" python scripts to execute on Windows?

Tags: windows, scripting, python

I have Python 2.5 installed on Windows XP and a collection of scripts available in a certain directory. According to this [article](http://www.imladris.com/Scripts/PythonForWindows.html) by Amanda Birmingham I can setup up a path for the Python executable and the one for where the scripts live. Which means I can do this:

```
c:\>python script.py
```

Is there a way I can perhaps register .py files so I can execute them like so:

```
c:\>script.py
```

without including a *shebang* or *env* line in the script.

Less typing equals good. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes :) That's actually [FAQ #2](http://www.python.org/doc/faq/windows/#how-do-i-make-python-scripts-executable):

> If you'd rather be able to execute the script by simple typing 'foo' with no extension you need to add .py to the PATHEXT environment variable.

Edit: Of course, don't forget to add the Python install directory to the PATH, and to launch another instance of your command interpreter if you modify the systemwide or the user PATH and/or PATHEXT by means outside of that command interpreter.

Further edit: In case I misunderstood your question: I'm assuming you're only interested in launching python scripts without having to type in the .py extension *from the cmd.exe command line*. PATHEXT is a mechanism specific to the cmd.exe shell and other shells (as well as `CreateProcess()` and friends) won't care about it in the least.

Comment: Does the redirection bug the FAQ mentions for Win NT exist in Windows XP? I ask because Windows XP is based on NT, correct?

Comment: No, that actually applies to Windows NT. 2000 and up were fixed.

Comment: Edit: Just reconfirmed. On both 2000 and XP tacking :.PY to the end of PATHEXT works like a charm, .py scripts run without requiring the extension or any alteration of the actual script itself. Of course, ensure you've added the Python install directory to the PATH.

Comment: Re: Running without the file extension: Not a big deal. But I see my problem now. It works as described in cmd.exe but silly me, I'm trying to run it that way in the bash shell using Cygwin. **smack** But thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Welcome. I'm using msys for my rather limited Win32 needs (I crosscompile mostly everything from Linux) and the two share common roots. I'll try to figure out a solution, and if I get it to work I'll leave a comment to the question and we can test it under Cygwin. I'd rather not install a cyg distribution at the moment, still too traumatized from last time :)

Comment: Nope, can't be done without patching bash, and maintaining a bash branch just to avoid typing .py or creating some symlinks borders on insanity :)

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. :) I guess if I want to avoid the additional typing I'll have to have a set of aliases or something.

Comment: Great, i'll check this out for Perl. 

I am surprised that this accepted answer hasn't got any votes except mine... i don't think we have a limited amount of votes peoples...

Comment: Glad to be of help, Mark. It did get votes, Jonathon voted it up. However, someone else who will probably go unnamed voted it down. Happens...

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue with PHP.

http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.legacy.index.php#install.windows.legacy.commandline (Edit: Seems command line usage for PHP is now "legacy")

One thing that I found was being able to use PHP scripts as filters ...

```
DIR C:\ | scripts\script | more
```

(for example - where scripts\script is a PHP script - NOTE : No PHP reference).

The registry change is required for this. Works for all of those interpreter type languages on windows (PHP, Python, Perl, Ruby).

Answer (score 0):

PATHEXT will allow you to leave off ".py", but that's not what you are asking, right?

If you want to associate a file extension with an application on Windows, you can:

1. Open an Explorer window.
2. Choose "Folder options" from the Tools menu.
3. Click the "File Types" tab.
4. Click the "New" button (assuming that PY/PYC/PYW are not already there).
5. Type in the extension (e.g. "py", "pyc" or "pyw") and click "OK"
6. Click the "Change..." button.
7. Choose "Select the program from a list"
8. Find your Python interpreter (e.g. python.exe or pythonw.exe in C:\Python2X)
9. Ok your way back out.

These are instructions for XP.  I presume that Vista and Win7 are basically the same, although you probably get to the list in some other way.

Comment: Leaving off .py is exactly what Jonathon was asking. And considering that he's using Cygwin, I assume he's quite familiar with changing shell file associations. And the Pythin Win32 installer already associates the required extensions with the Python interpreter.