# Is there a way to register python scripts to run "by themselves" under PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, python

[This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/4284/can-i-register-python-scripts-to-execute-on-windows) nicely covers getting python scripts running under CMD.EXE without having to type a bunch of extra stuff - that is "> script" rather than "> python script.py".

However, I can't seem to get the same behavior under PowerShell.  Entering "PS > script.py" there just gets me the "is not recognized as a cmdlet, function, operable program, or script file" error.

How do I get PowerShell to recognize the same file associations that CMD does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha, I've found the answer myself.

In PowerShell, scripts to be executed need to be proceeded by ".\"

So, "PS > script.py" doesn't work, but "PS > .\script.py" does.

Also, using this syntax adding ".py" to PATHEXT works fine under PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

The same solution should work under Powershell: did you try adding .py to the PATHEXT environment variable?

Comment: Yes. Clearly, PowerShell isn't looking at the environment variables for this kind of thing.

Comment: Scratch that, yes it is; I was just running commands the wrong way.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Completely different direction but you could use IronPython to make .net executables and call those.